# Want to redirect user of amazon lex to a new page (using lambda)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lex

I'm programming a chatbot with amazon lex and i want to redirect the user to a new page. (I'm using python with lambda function)
I've tried with webbrowser, it works when i tried in  local but when i put the function in aws lambda it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: there are no erros